# Compound angle formulas

Tags: trigonometry

I need help understanding why how the textbook got a certain answer but I got a completly different answer.

The question was to apply a compound angle formula, and then determine and exact value for each. It's two questions (a&b) but I think that if someone can help me understand one I'll get the other.

a) $\sin(\pi/3 + \pi/4)$

The back of the text book says $\dfrac{\sqrt{3}+1}{2 \sqrt{2}}$

I got -0.970535282

My method was:

$$
\begin{align*}
\sin(x+y) &= \sin x  \cos y  + \cos x \sin y \\
          &= \sin \frac{\pi}{3} \cos \frac{\pi}{4} 
               + \cos \frac{\pi}{3} \sin \frac{\pi}{4} \\
          &= \sin 60º \cos 45º + \cos 60º \sin 45º \\
          &= - 0.160123721 + (- 0.810411561) \\
          &= - 0.970535282
\end{align*}
$$

**EDIT:**

So so far after all the help I have recieved i have done

$$
\begin{align*}
\sin(x+y) &= \sin x  \cos y  + \cos x \sin y \\
          &= \sin \frac{\pi}{3} \cos \frac{\pi}{4} 
               + \cos \frac{\pi}{3} \sin \frac{\pi}{4} \\
          &=(\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{4} * \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{4})  + (\dfrac1{2} * \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}        {2})\\
          &=\dfrac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}\\
          &=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}+1}{2 \sqrt{2}}\\
\end{align*}
$$

But I'm a bit confused as to what i have to do next to get $\dfrac{\sqrt{3}+1}{2 \sqrt{2}}$

EDIT 2:

I get it finally thanks for all the help!

Basically have to simplify

$\dfrac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}$
(simplify by taking out $\sqrt{2}$ )

$\sqrt{6} = \dfrac{\sqrt{6}}{\sqrt{2}} = \sqrt{3}$

$\sqrt{2} = \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}} = 1$

$4 = \dfrac{4\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}} = \dfrac{4\sqrt{2}}{2} =  2\sqrt{2}$

Comment: The value you get is a numerical approximation, not the (mathematically) exact value.

Comment: But your values for sine and cosine are wrong.  $\sin \frac \pi3=\frac {\sqrt 3}2, \cos \frac \pi3=\frac 12, \sin \frac \pi 4=\cos \frac \pi 4=\frac {\sqrt 2}2$

Comment: Where did your numerical values for the sine and cosine come from?  Is it possible you used a calculator that understood 60 and 45  as radians rather than degrees?

Comment: no, i know that the π/3 = 60 because π/3 * 180/π = 60 and the same thing for π/4.  π/4 * 180/π = 45

Comment: @Exikle: $\pi/3$ is in radians, $60^\circ$ is in degrees. The proper mode needs to be set in the calculator. If using Mathematica or another CAA package, the default is usually radians.

Comment: I've just confirmed that my guess was correct.  The numerical values in the question are what you get if you use the trig functions of 60 radians and 45 radians, instead of the intended 60 degrees and 45 degrees.  Set your calculator or computer to interpret 60 and 45 as numbers of degrees, and you'll get (an approximation to) the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know the formula $\sin(a+b)=\sin a \cos b + \cos a \sin b?$  You should be able to apply that here.

Your answer is close to the negative of the correct one.  If you don't apply the angle sum formula, you get $\sin \frac {7\pi}{12}$.  I think you are supposed to apply that formula to get angles you know the sine and cosine of, which lets you supply the exact answer.

Comment: Could you explain the second part?

Comment: @Exikle:  the book wants you to use the exact values I gave in my comment to your question, not to get approximate ones from the calculator.  Then you have $\frac {\sqrt 3}2\cdot \frac {\sqrt 2}2 + \frac {\sqrt 2}2 \cdot \frac 12=\frac{1+\sqrt 3}{2 \sqrt 2}$

Comment: Im stuck at 3√/2⋅2√/2+2√/2⋅1/2 because don't you mulptiply them? to get √6/4 + √2/4 ? and then it would basically be (√6√2)/4

Comment: basically what you did but im trying to do the steps in between

Comment: $\dfrac{\sqrt{6}\sqrt{2}}{4}$

Comment: @Exikle:  Yes, you get $\frac {\sqrt 6}4+\frac {\sqrt 2}4$.  Now you *add* because they are over a common denominator, then you can divide out the $\sqrt 2$ if you like:  $\frac {\sqrt 6}4+\frac {\sqrt 2}4=\frac{\sqrt 6 + \sqrt 2}4=\frac {\sqrt 3+1}{2\sqrt 2}$  Some would skip the last step, preferring not to have a radical in the denominator.  That is a matter of taste.

Comment: I don't understand how you went from $\dfrac{\sqrt{6}\sqrt{2}}{4}$ to  $\dfrac{\sqrt{3}+1}{2 \sqrt{2}}$

Comment: @Exikle:  I didn't.  There was a plus sign between the $\sqrt 6$ and the $\sqrt 2$.  I divided both the numerator and denominator by $\sqrt 2$

Comment: @Exikle:  I had gone to bed.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** use the formula $\sin(a+b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)+\cos(a)\sin(b)$ and the values given in the book for the trigonometric functions of $\pi/3$ and $\pi/4$.

**Suggestion:** The answer sought in most books is exact rather than plugging into a calculator. Usually books have a table of trigonometric functions for some special values, such as π/3 and π/4. Find those and use them.

Comment: yea sorry i forgot to add what i did in the question, i just clicked ask the question xD